# Can we write an element in a super Grassmannian as a pair of matrices?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, algebraic-groups

Super Grassmannians are introduced by Manin, see [for example](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/227218661_On_the_rigidity_of_super-Grassmannians).

Elements in a grassmannian can be written as matrices, see [for example](http://www.macs.hw.ac.uk/~simonm/schubertcalculusreview.pdf).

Can we write an element in a super Grassmannian as a pair of matrices? I search on google but did not find such results. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think the first reference you give (to the paper of Onishchik) answers the question. The super-Grassmannian is defined to have underlying space a product of ordinary Grassmannians, plus some structure sheaf. Therefore, points are pairs of linear subspaces which you can represent by matrices.